# installing python packages on kubernetes using helm charts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use some external python packages using pip which would let me use snowflake on apache airflow.

I have a dockerfile and I am using helm chats to install airflow.

Now I need to add some python dependencies to integrate snowflake and airflow and I have two ways of doing this.

**Idea 1:**

Adding python packages to docker file using requirements.txt file which will have my pip packages and then docker build using this dockerfile

**Idea 2:**

Adding python packages to values.yaml file and using this to upgrade my helm chart for airflow so that it installs airflow and these packages.

I tried these two and it doesn't seem to work. I don't see my packages.

Are there any alternative or recommended ways of doing this?

Comment: Why not just upgrade the image？

Comment: upgrade docker image? I am not sure how to do this. Is there a way to add pip install package while upgrade? I have few packages to add.

Comment: [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) or 1. docker run -it xxx 2. install packages 3. docker commit xxx 4. update image

Comment: The Docker documentation includes a [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial that walks through the custom image process.  You can build your image `FROM` any other image and put the Dockerfile into source control.  Do _not_ use `docker commit`: you'll have trouble recreating the image if, say, you need to update the underlying Airflow layer.

Comment: Installing packages in a container is not something you can do at the Kubernetes layer and not something it's possible to do in Helm.  (And it's not a great idea in general: you can have a production outage if a pod is rescheduled on to a new node, but PyPI happens to be down at that instant and you can't do the installation.)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by updating the dockerfile as other users suggested above.

add your python packages to a requirements.txt file and save it to a folder ( your working directory)

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest

USER airflow
WORKDIR C:/Users/my_folder_which_has_requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can also do this without requirements.txt like

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest

USER airflow
RUN pip install "package1" "package2" "package3"
```